# How to swap object value by set of index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, swap

I have array like this

```
arrayValue=[
    { value: 1}, 
    { value: 2}, 
    { value: "line break"}, 
    { value: 3}, 
    { value: 4}, 
    { value: "line break"}, 
    { value: 1}, 
    { value: 1}
]
```

I have to swap forward or backward value by 2 set of index, each 3 index of value having up & down arrow when i am click up/down arrow have to swap based on that two index forward or backward.for example 0th, 3rd, 6th having arrow. any one help this?

Comment: Not super clear what you're after.

Comment: The wat????????

Comment: Difficult to understand your scenario and issue.

Comment: I don't know how to explain my problem.
Ex. If i need to swap first two elements means i need result 
arrayValue=[
    { value: 3}, 
    { value: 4}, 
    { value: "line break"}, 
    { value: 1}, 
    { value: 2}, 
    { value: "line break"}, 
    { value: 1}, 
    { value: 1}
] @DamianCzapiewski

Comment: @RaviKumarGopalakrishnan check my answer but I don't know if it is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it'll be something like the below.

```
function _move(arr, idx, dir) {
    var res = arr.slice();
    var thrown = res.splice(idx, 1)[0];
    if (dir === 'up') {
        res.splice(idx-1, 0, thrown);
    } else {
        res.splice(idx+1, 0, thrown);
    }
    return res;
} 

Array.prototype.up = function (idx) {
    return _move(this, idx, 'up');
};

Array.prototype.down = function (idx) {
    return _move(this, idx, 'down');
};

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(
    a.up(2), // 1 3 2 4 5
    a.down(2) // 1 2 4 3 5
);
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to swap `n` items, left ones starting at `L` and right ones starting at `R` - call `swapItems(arr, L, R, n)`. Here's implementation I've written:

```
function swapItems(arr, leftIdx, rightIdx, itemsNum) {
    var leftOnes = arr.splice(leftIdx, itemsNum);
    var rightOnes = arr.splice(rightIdx - itemsNum, itemsNum);
    arr.splice(leftIdx, 0, ...rightOnes);
    arr.splice(rightIdx, 0, ...leftOnes);
}

var arr = [1, 2, 'br', 3, 4, 'br', 1, 1];

// first pair starts at 0, another pair start at 3, number of items to affect = 2
swapItems(arr, 0, 3, 2);
// arr = [3, 4, 'br', 1, 2, 'br', 1, 1]
```